# I am having difficulty with my deal method

Tags: java, poker

In my `PokerDeck`  class I cannot get my deal method to run without producing duplicates. Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

```
import java.util.*;

public class PokerDeck {
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = PokerCard.NUMBER_OF_SUITS * PokerCard.NUMBER_OF_RANKS;
    // Instance Variables
    private boolean[] deck;
    private int numberOfCardsInDeck;

    // Constructor
    public PokerDeck()

    {
        deck = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_CARDS];
        for (int j = 0; j < deck.length; j++)
            for (PokerCard.CardSuit suit : PokerCard.CardSuit.values())
                for (PokerCard.CardRank rank : PokerCard.CardRank.values())
                    deck[j] = true;

    }

    // Accessor
    public int getNumberOfCardsInDeck() {
        numberOfCardsInDeck = NUMBER_OF_CARDS;
        return this.numberOfCardsInDeck;

    }

    // Mutator:
    // Return all 52 PokerCards to this PokerDeck
    public void shuffle() {
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * deck.length);
            deck[i] = deck[index];
        }

    }

    // Mutator:
    // Return a randomly selected PokerCard from this PokerDeck
    // Update the state of this PokerDeck to reflect removal of
    // the selected PokerCard
    // Exception thrown if this PokerDeck is "empty"

    public PokerCard deal() {
        Random dealer = new Random();
        int ran = dealer.nextInt(deck.length);
        if (numberOfCardsInDeck == 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("Empty Deck");

        if (deck[ran] == false)
            ran = dealer.nextInt(deck.length);

        deck[ran] = false;
        int suit = ran / 13;
        int rank = ran % 13;

        return new PokerCard(PokerCard.CardSuit.values()[suit], PokerCard.CardRank.values()[rank]);
    }
}
```

I tried at least five different code and all of them either do not run or they run and return duplicates.

Comment: what do you mean by returns duplicates?

Comment: well you aren't marking the PokerCard as dealt before returning, so in the context of your code there can be duplicates.

Comment: the line if (deck[dealer.nextInt(deck.length)] = false) should be changed to: if (deck[dealer.nextInt(deck.length)] == false) , but I'm not sure if that will solve your problem...

Comment: your shuffle is also problematic: you'll lose about half your cards at each shuffle

Comment: i have editied my code to show the original

Comment: it's not an if it's a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of things wrong with this code. Your problem is, because you are randoming more and more instead of using te `ran` variable you declared at the beggining of deal method. After you declared your `ran` variable, don't do `dealer.nextInt(deck.length)`, replace it with `ran`.

Your shuffling is not really shuffling, check this: [Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array).

Comparing (like `if(something == false)`) should be done with `==`, you are doing it with `=` (but you probably just pasted it wrong).

In your getter this `numberOfCardsInDeck = NUMBER_OF_CARDS;` is wrong, unless you wanted to 'refresh' a deck instead of just get a number of cards, but I don't think so, remove that line.

Triple for in your constructor is wrong, you need only the first one, it doesn't make a difference here (except performance), but fix it.

Also I suggest rewriting all this, do a Card object (class) with suit and rank enums, make a Deck object with List of Card objects, make a deck.getCard() method that removes the last card from the deck, make the deck.shuffle() method that shuffles deck (you will have a List of Cards now, not an array, so you will be able to do Collections.shuffle(cardList), simple).

Also, change this:

```java
if (deck[dealer.nextInt(deck.length)] == false)
            dealer.nextInt(deck.length);
```

To something like this:

```java
while (deck[ran] == false)
            ran = dealer.nextInt(deck.length);
```

Comment: my professor says that there is no need to exchange cards and that the shuffle method is supposed to basically do the same as the constructor

Comment: what am i supposed to replace the code with the getter method then?

Comment: my professor provided us with a PokerCard class and a test class so the code has to be with suit and rank enums and a deck arrray of booleans

Comment: Yes, shuffle is wrong, check link I gave you. Remove first line in getter method and put it in constructor. Change that 'if' to 'while' like I wrote in my answer. Add 'numberOfCardsInDeck--' before returning from deal method.

Comment: the link you gave me is saying to swap or exchange the cards which i am not supposed to do. the shuffle method is supposed to basically do the same as the constructor

Answer (score 0):

there are a few scary errors which make me wonder just how much you read your own code:

1. the reuse of random here:

   ```
   if (deck[dealer.nextInt(deck.length)] == false)
   ```

   means that you will randomize again and not use the previously generated `ran`.
2. this block

   ```
   if (deck[dealer.nextInt(deck.length)] == false)
       dealer.nextInt(deck.length);
   ```

   is useless since `dealer.nextInt(deck.length)` simply creates a value without storing anything.
   I supposed you were trying to "keep trying until you find a valid card" so it should look more like this:

   ```
   while (deck[ran] == false)
       ran = dealer.nextInt(deck.length);
   ```
3. the `Shuffle()` method here simply duplicates values eveywhere in your deck since instead of swapping you simply replace the first value with the second, losing the first. to avoid that simply add

   ```
   boolean b = deck[i];
   deck[i] = deck[index];
   deck[index] = b;
   ```

   to make it a swap.

that's all i found after a first reading.

Comment: like i said in my previous comment i already spoke to my professor about my shuffle method and he said its supposed to basically do the same as the constructor